Ошибка при запуске виртуальной машины в virtualbox

Я запускаю виртуальную машину, и у меня появляется эта ошибка. ОС - windows

Не установлен ли у вас некий Windhawk или ещё какая утилита, которая серьёзно вмешивается в работу Windows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992120/why-cant-i-start-the-virtual-machine-i-just-built-using-vitrualbox https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=109422

Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?

@user7860670 Ну так то не любые окна позволяют скопировать из себя текст.

@CrazyElf Если не позволяют скопировать, то можно воспользоваться OCR или просто перепечатать руками, на худой конец.

@CrazyElf ошибка наверняка записалась в лог (правда, нужно ещё знать, где его искать)
